# Linker error not related to Linker

Tags: c++, c, linker, linker-errors

I have a very specific case of Linker error :

> 'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker 4 [arm-linux-gnueabihf]'
>   arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -lpthread
>   **./src/FPGA_Peripherals/AUX_IMU/AUX_IMU_functions.o**
>   ./src/main.o: In
>   function main':
>   ../src/main.cpp:7:
>   undefined reference to **`function()'**

the error output is truncated for purpose of this post. The error and the object, where the function definitions lies, is highlighted.

---

The code is compiled and linked using DS-5 C/C++ Eclipse Platform, with the GCC 4.x [arm-linux-gnueabihd] (DS-5 built-in) tool-chain :

- GCC C++ Compiler 4 [arm-linux-gnueabihf]
- GCC C Compiler 4 [arm-linux-gnueabihf]
- GCC Assembler 4 [arm-linux-gnueabihf]
- GCC C Linker 4 [arm-linux-gnueabihf]
- GCC C++ Linker 4 [arm-linux-gnueabihf]
- GCC Archiver 4 [arm-linux-gnueabihf]

With Gnu Make Builder.

---

Source code is structured in folders :

- src

  *main.cpp*

  - FPGA_peripherals

    - AUX_IMU

    *header.h*

    *AUX_IMU_functions.c*

---

Minimalistic code producing the error :

**main.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"

int main() {
    function();
    return 0;
}
```

**header.h**

```
void function(void);
```

**AUX_IMU_functions.c**

```
#include "header.h" 

void function(void){
    int i = 3;
};
```

---

The C code is correctly compiled using GCC C Compiler 4 [arm-linux-gnueabihf].
The C++ code (other files, not included within this example), are correctly compiled using GCC C++ Linker 4 [arm-linux-gnueabihf].

---

This apparently is not a Linker related problem, but what else to check, if Linker still produces this error ?

---

**The error disappears, once I re-name the files to .hpp and .cpp**. Why is that ? Does GCC C and GCC C++ produces incompatible .o objects ?

Comment: Note that the final semicolon in `void function(void){
    int i = 3;
};` is superfluous.  Almost, but not quite harmless; under strict compiler options, you'll get a warning about an empty global declaration, which will probably confuse you.  Initializers and types need a semicolon after the close brace; functions do not.

Comment: Your error occurs because of C++ type-safe linkage which mangles function names.  You need to tell the C++ compiler that the `function()` has C linkage: `extern "C" void function(void);`.  You normally do that by using `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `extern "C"` / `#endif` before the function declaration, or use the `extern "C" {` before and `}` conditionally after a block of C function declarations.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well, it is a constraint violation, so the compilation is allowed to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error occurs because of C++ type-safe linkage, which mangles function names.  You need to tell the C++ compiler that the `function()` has C linkage:

```
extern "C" void function(void);
```

However, if the same header should be used by both the C and C++ compilers, you normally do that by using

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void function(void);
```

for a single function declaration, or use

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif 

void function(void);
int  response(int arg);
…

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

around a block of function declarations for functions with C linkage.

You can also use your existing header in C, and in your C++ code, use:

```
extern "C" {
#include "header.h"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have actually tried to use 'extern "C" ' before, but it produces other error, because of the GCC C compiler, which doesnt recognizes it. Now I understand why it is so vital to add the #ifdef _cplusplus